# R Issue getting Min and Max from dates in a column

Tags: r, group-by, max, min

I am trying to get the Min and Max from a group of dates in a column.
When I run my code (below) I get the Max date for the first entry when looking for the min (the rest are ok), and the min for the max entry for the first entry when looking at the max (the rest are ok.

Data:

```
structure(list(PR.Number = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("PR1234", "PR1235", "PR1236", "PR1237", "PR1238"
), class = "factor"), Date.received = structure(c(2L, 1L, 7L, 
10L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("01/02/2024", "05/01/2022", "09/09/2023", 
"09/09/2025", "10/03/2023", "10/03/2024", "15/07/2022", "16/11/2022", 
"16/11/2023", "30/09/2022"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code Max:

```
R_Date.Test %>% 
  group_by(PR.Number) %>% 
  slice_max(Date.received)
```

Code Min:

```
R_Date.Test %>% 
  group_by(PR.Number) %>% 
  slice_min(Date.received)
```

Min Output:
PR.Number Date.received

1 PR1234    01/02/2024  < this is wrong 05/01/2022
2 PR1235    15/07/2022
3 PR1236    16/11/2022
4 PR1237    10/03/2023
5 PR1237    10/03/2023
6 PR1238    09/09/2023

Max Output:
PR.Number Date.received

1 PR1234    05/01/2022  < this is wrong 01/02/2024
2 PR1235    30/09/2022
3 PR1236    16/11/2023
4 PR1237    10/03/2024
5 PR1238    09/09/2025

Comment: Your "dates" aren't real dates. They are factors with labels that look like dates. You need to convert them to dates first. An extra line like `mutate(Date.received = lubridate::dmy(as.character(Date.received))) %>%` before your `group_by` should achieve that, then it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Date.received` is a factor not a Date object
so try :

```
R_Date.Test$Date.received <-  as.Date(df$Date.received , "%d/%m/%Y")

# then apply your code above

R_Date.Test %>% 
    group_by(PR.Number) %>% 
    slice_min(Date.received)
```

Comment: Thank you. New it would be something basic. I was to busy fixating on the fact it _looked_ right and not what it was actually was